# Looks like javascript doesn't recognize new elements after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got an element which loads data in it according to a block that was clicked.

Using Ajax I load an entire phpfile inside my index after a variable is sent to it.

For example:

Block 1 is clicked, $block (containing string: block1) is sent to my php script where I place $block in my query to retrieve the correct data. After that I load the result on my index.

This works as it should but all javascript functionalities are broken. When I add the php script in my index and don't retrieve it using ajax but add the word manually (where $block would normally be) all javascript works fine.

So it seems when the result is loaded, the javascript is already finished or doesn't recognize it. How can I fix that?

My code where I retrieve it:

```
$('.handmouse').on('click', function(e){
        var alias = $(this).attr("data-attribute");
        var clicked = true;
        $.post("ajax/blokken.php", {
          dienstnaam : alias
        }, function(data) {
            $(".tabwrapper").html(data);
        });
        $('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
        if(clicked != true){
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(".tabwrapper").offset().top
          }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should do everything inside the success callback of ajax call

Comment: Everything after your *Ajax* call will be executed **before** the ajax call is finished. That is because Javascript is not **async**. If you want to do things after your *ajax* has finished loading, put that logic into a function and call that function from the `success` method in your *ajax* call.

Comment: Aside from the above, `if (clicked != true)` will never hit

Comment: @binariedMe / Randy Can you give an example? My Ajax is not that good.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I know I am still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your code into `success` method of your ajax call and not after your ajax call, because **ajax call is async**.

```
$('.handmouse').on('click', function(e){
    var alias = $(this).attr("data-attribute");
    var clicked = true;

    $.post("ajax/blokken.php", {
        dienstnaam : alias
    }, function(data) {
        $(".tabwrapper").html(data);
        $('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
        if(clicked != true){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".tabwrapper").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```